# In Battlefield 3, is there a console command to disable chat?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

Even in 1080p, the chat box is rather annoyingly sized on a 22in monitor. Does anyone know if there is a console command to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

Since the last patch there is a key that lets you toggle the chat between "always", "popup" and "never".

By default it is bound to <kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently a hacky way to do this, per

http://forums.electronicarts.co.uk/battlefield-3-pc/1448520-howto-customize-chatbox-bf3.html

- open `PROF_SAVE_profile` with Notepad
- change these values (example values are for 1024x768)

  ```
  GstRender.ScreenSafeAreaHeight 0.048000  
  GstRender.ScreenSafeAreaWidth 1.030000
  ```
- you can also adjust `GstRender.ScreenSafeAreaHeight`

However, it does look like this interferes with other aspects of the HUD, so it might not be a great or workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I checked all the things in the list:

http://www.battlefield3online.com/some-useful-battlefield-3-console-commands/2991/

and I didn't find anything, though **Online.ChatSettings**, or **Vars.max-chat-message-chars** could be used I think.

Probably there is no command like that.